# Redoing loop whenever a duplicate is found (Lotto program C#)

Tags: c#, for-loop, duplicates

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static Random randy = new Random();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 7;

        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
           // if (i == count)
        {
            int myInt = nextNo();

            string myNum = String.Format("{0}\t", myInt.ToString());
            TextBox1.Text += myNum;
            TextBox2.Text = ("These are your numbers fsdjio"); 
        }
    }

    int nextNo()
    {
        return randy.Next(1, 45);
    }
}
```

**strong text**

The problem is that I will often get duplicate numbers. Is there a way to make the loop only progress if the numbers are not the same? thanks

I am using a for loop and the Random class to make a lottery program with 6 numbers. However I will often get recurring numbers. Do I have to code it so that the whole process repeats until there are six different numbers? Thanks first time poster here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to format your code, so that it is nice to read. You can use the gray "edit" link below your question for that. This will increase your chances of getting a good answer, and it's a sign of respect to the people who help you here.

Comment: I guess this is homework.  If you want to impress your teacher/lecturer, then you may want to have a look at the Fisher-Yates algorithm which is perfect for this situation.  It's also pretty easy to implement.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should not do again the whole loop. Just do as follows:

```
var set = new HashSet<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    while(!set.Add(nextNo()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need random unique numbers. You need to shuffle an existing set of numbers. Their are plenty of questions (and answers) on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fisher%20yates%20%5Bc#%5D&submit=search) and [google](http://www.google.de/search?q=fisher+yates+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest) about this topic. Take a search for the *fisher yates shuffle* algorithm and use it on your set of unique numbers.